# How To Replace character with clicked element at current cursor position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a contenteditable div and when you type @ the list shows up. Now I want to be able to insert some text when I click on li element at current cursor position in contenteditable div. Somehow I need to find cursor position and replace @ with some text. Let's say I type 'Javascript is @' to produce 'Javascript is awesome'.

```js
$('.reply').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 86) {
    $('.list').show();
  } else {
    $('.list').hide();
  }
})
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}

.reply {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reply" contentEditable="true"></div>
<ul class="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You say it appears on `@` keypress, yet keyCode 86 is `v`...?

Comment: Do you want to replace the @ by the text grabbed from the li element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan keyCode is fine alt + v produces 86, i can use something like e.originalEvent.data == '@' to trigger when someone types @. That's not an issue, the real issue is how to find cursor position so I can insert text at that position. I don't want just append text at the end, I want to be able to add it at the middle of the text if I typed '@' there. So I'm guessing I need to find somehow current cursor position and when i click on li insert text at that current cursor position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to detect if the user pressed the **@** key you need to check if the **alt** key is down too beside checking for a single keyCode.

```
$('.reply').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 81) {
    $('.list').show();
  } else {
    $('.list').hide();
  }
});
```

To get the content of the li element upon click you need to attach a click event listener to the list and retrieve the text inside the callback function using **e.target.firstChild.data**.

Now things get a little tricky because you are using a contenteditable **div** and not a **textarea**. A div doesn't offer built-in methods to retrieve the position of the cursor so we need to implement it on our own using the **Selection** API.

First add two new properties to a HTML div element

```
HTMLDivElement.prototype.selectionStart = 0;
HTMLDivElement.prototype.selectionEnd = 0;
```

and attach several listeners to the div element to check if something's written into it

```
['mousedown', 'mouseup', 'keydown', 'keyup'].forEach(function(evt) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("reply")[0].addEventListener(evt, update);
});
```

in case it is - update the new properties accordingly

```
function update(e) {
  var caret = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
  e.target.selectionStart = caret;
  e.target.selectionEnd = caret + window.getSelection().focusOffset;
}
```

Now things are as simple as retrieving the cursor position inside the click event handler of the li element subtract 1 and replace the content with the appropriate text.

Here's an example:

```js
HTMLDivElement.prototype.selectionStart = 0;
HTMLDivElement.prototype.selectionEnd = 0;

function update(e) {
  var caret = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
  e.target.selectionStart = caret;
  e.target.selectionEnd = caret + window.getSelection().focusOffset;
}

['mousedown', 'mouseup', 'keydown', 'keyup'].forEach(function(evt) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("reply")[0].addEventListener(evt, update);
});

$('.reply').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 81) {
    $('.list').show();
  } else {
    $('.list').hide();
  }
});



$('.list').on('click', function(e) {
  var text = $('.reply').text();
  var pos = $('.reply')[0].selectionStart - 1;
  text = text.substring(0, pos) + e.target.firstChild.data + text.substring(pos + 1);
  $('.reply').text(text);
});

$('.list').hide();
```

```css
.reply {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reply" contentEditable="true">

</div>

<ul class="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I want. Very nice, thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, it's not gonna work. We can't just say replace '@' with something, it's always gonna replace first '@'. For example: 'you are great@man and I want to replace this @' - It's gonna replace first '@'

Comment: I modified my Code above to replace the last occurence of @.

Comment: That's still not gonna work, the current code looking for a last '@' not last typed '@', so basically I can have a email address at the end of the text and if I put my cursor in the middle and type '@' list will show up and if I click it's gonna replace last '@' not last typed. I'm struggling with this :(

Comment: Now I know what you mean. Well that's kinda tricky but doable. I revised my answer above.

Comment: I found a bug in this solution. When you hit enter and then you click on list item, it doesn't place text at right position

Answer (score 1):

You must add event on your list like this.

```
$('.list li').bind('click', function(){
    var inputValue = $(".reply").text();
  var indexOfAt = inputValue.indexOf('@');

  if(indexOfAt != -1){
    var modifiedText = $(".reply").text().replace('@',$(this).text());
    $(".reply").text(modifiedText);
  }
  $('.list').hide();
});
```

Comment: Well, that's not it. i don't want to append it to the rest of the text. I want to be able to add it at current cursor position. Maybe cursor is in the middle of the text and then I hit '@', I want to add text at that position, not at the end of the file.

Comment: Still not what I'm looking for, We can't just search for '@' index, we can have multiple @ in the text. We need the one lthat is last typed.